# Getting error on Case Condition using Shell Script in UNIX

Tags: shell

Can you please help me out in the below Shell script I am getting "command not found" error inside the Case condition

```
echo "Execution Flag is : ${exeFlag}"
while getopts ":f:l:d:r:h:o:n:" opt; do
echo "${opt}"
case "${opt}" in
    f)
        if "$OPTARG" != ""
        then
            echo "$OPTARG"
                        file="$OPTARG"
        else
            echo "Failed : $OPTARG"
            exeFlag="False"
        fi
        ;;
    l)
        if "$OPTARG" != ""
         then
            echo $OPTARG
            path="$OPTARG"
        else
            exeFlag="False"
        fi
        ;;
    d)
        if "$OPTARG" != ""
        then
            echo $OPTARG
            bed="$OPTARG"
        else
            exeFlag="False"
        fi
        ;;
    r)
        if "$OPTARG" != ""
        then
            echo $OPTARG
            rev="$OPTARG"
        else
            exeFlag="False"
        fi
        ;;
    h)
        if "$OPTARG" != ""
        then
            echo $OPTARG
            head="$OPTARG"
        else
            exeFlag="False"
        fi
        ;;
    o)
        opts="$OPTARG"
        ;;
    n)
        if $OPTARG != ""
         then
            echo "$OPTARG"
            hive_name="$OPTARG"
        else
            exeFlag="False"
        fi
        ;;
    *)
            echo "Invalid Tags"
        ;;
esac
done
echo "Execution Flag is : ${exeFlag}"
```

For all the variable, i am getting the error. I want "$OPTARG" as a simple text.

> variablename="$OPTARG"

Below is the full code: I want to pass those parameters from the case condition to function

```
#!/bin/bash
#################### functions #####################
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="$HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal"
startTime=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
exeFlag="True"

function Full_Check(){
    cmd_meta="./metadata_check.sh -v ${hive_name} -c read_from_file -l ${path} -f ${file}"
    cmd_content="./Content_Compare.sh -t read_file -c ../configs -f ${file} -r ${rev} -l ${path} -d ${bed} -e 1 -h ${head}"
    cmd_runctrl="./run_control_test.sh -v ${hive_name} -c extract_from_hdfs -l  ${path} -f ${file} -r ${rev} -d {bed}"

    ##Execute the commands:
    echo cmd_meta >> "${path}/${hive_name}.full_meta.log"
    cmd_meta >> "${path}/${hive_name}.full_meta.log"

    echo cmd_content >> "${path}/${hive_name}.full_content.log"
    cmd_content >> "${path}/${hive_name}.full_content.log"

    echo cmd_runctrl >> "${path}/${hive_name}.full_RunControl.log"
    cmd_runctrl >> "${path}/${hive_name}.full_RunControl.log"
}

echo "Execution Flag is : ${exeFlag}"
while getopts ":f:l:d:r:h:o:n:" opt; do
echo "${opt}"
case "${opt}" in
    f)
        if "$OPTARG" != ""
        then
            echo "$OPTARG"
                        file="$OPTARG"
        else
            echo "Failed : $OPTARG"
            exeFlag="False"
        fi
        ;;
    l)
        if "$OPTARG" != ""
         then
            echo $OPTARG
            path="$OPTARG"
        else
            exeFlag="False"
        fi
        ;;
    d)
        if "$OPTARG" != ""
        then
            echo $OPTARG
            bed="$OPTARG"
        else
            exeFlag="False"
        fi
        ;;
    r)
        if "$OPTARG" != ""
        then
            echo $OPTARG
            rev="$OPTARG"
        else
            exeFlag="False"
        fi
        ;;
    h)
        if "$OPTARG" != ""
        then
            echo $OPTARG
            head="$OPTARG"
        else
            exeFlag="False"
        fi
        ;;
    o)
        opts="$OPTARG"
        ;;
    n)
        if $OPTARG != ""
         then
            echo "$OPTARG"
            hive_name="$OPTARG"
        else
            exeFlag="False"
        fi
        ;;
    *)
            echo "Invalid Tags"
        ;;
esac
done
echo "Execution Flag is : ${exeFlag}"
if "${exeFlag}" != "False" 
then
    Full_Check
else
    echo "Please check the format of the command #./Filecheck.sh -f <file> -l <path> -d <bed> -r <rev> -h <head> -n <hive_name> -o <others>#"
fi
endTime=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
echo "start time ${startTime}"
echo "end time ${endTime}"
```

EDIT: Error Image
[image]

Comment: `if x` attempts to run the command "x". To test a value, use the [`test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) command: `if [ "$OPTARG" != "" ]`

Comment: i even used the [] in my code but hardly any luck... Same error

Comment: With the exact spacing I showed? `["$OPTARG"` is not the same as `[ "$OPTARG"` and `""]` is not the same as `"" ]`. Add the entire, exact, error message you see to your question. The error includes **which** command is not found.

Comment: @jhnc : It worked.. Thank you, If you can pasted this in Answer section, I will mark it as Accepted.